# javascript empty text ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, class, function

I have a php script and i'm using ajax with it. I have a textarea form connect with the ajax class

The problem when I pass a text like (`&some text`) the function return an empty text, I guess that I have a problem with (`&`).

The javascript function:

```
function sendFormData(idForm, dataSource, divID, ifLoading)
{
  var postData='';
  var strReplaceTemp;

  if(XMLHttpRequestObject)
  {
    XMLHttpRequestObject.open("POST", dataSource);
    XMLHttpRequestObject.setRequestHeader("Method", "POST " + dataSource + " HTTP/1.1");
      XMLHttpRequestObject.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
      if (XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState == 4 &&
          XMLHttpRequestObject.status == 200)
      {
        try
        {
          var objDiv = document.getElementById(divID);
          objDiv.innerHTML = XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText;
        }
        catch(e){document.write("sendFormData: getElementById(divID) Error");}
      }
      else
      {
        if(ifLoading)
        {
          try
          {
            var objDiv = document.getElementById(divID);
            objDiv.innerHTML = "<img src=loading.gif>";
          }
          catch(e){document.write("sendFormData->ifLoading: getElementById(divID) Error");}
        }
      }
    }

    for(i=0; i<document.getElementById(idForm).elements.length - 1; i++)
    {
      strReplaceTemp = document.getElementById(idForm).elements[i].name;
      postData += "&aryFormData["+strReplaceTemp+"][]="+document.getElementById(idForm).elements[i].value;
    }

    postData += "&parm="+new Date().getTime();
    try
    {
      XMLHttpRequestObject.send(postData);
    }
    catch(e){document.write("sendFormData: XMLHttpRequestObject.send Error");}
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post a snippet of the code that you are using? It might be easier to answer if we know the context of your question.

Comment: This post seriously could use a better title.

Comment: Oh my, hand-written AJAX.  /shudder

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your & is encoded with &amp; if you're passing it using Javascript. All & need to be encoded, or some browsers can freak out a bit, and any validater will complain at you.

Answer (score 0):

when i see HTML and & and problem, i look to make sure that my character encoding is all properly specified.

also, the code in your PHP script may be choking on an un/escaped '&' character.

Answer (score 0):

In your function, if you wrap document.getElementById(idForm).elements[i].value and even strReplaceTemp (in your postData +=) line with "encodeURI()", you won't have any issues with the data being properly received.

Comment: If its not working, then your PHP is likely to blame. You could try escape or encodeURIComponent instead of encodeURI, but encodeURI should do the trick. When you throw an alert(postData) inside of your try, what does it say?